# Copy Full worksheet including multiple defined range names using macro or VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I've been trying to build a workbook for my company to use to track sales.

The problem I'm running into is that I want each user to have their own workbook saved on their local computer for their own info.  This workbook uses a userform to submit data, which pulls info from a sheet in the workbook to autofill based on brand of device sold.

I want to be able to update this information on a network drive, and have the workbook updated automatically each time it is opened.

I've been able to do this for an individual range, with no problem.

I want to be able to do this for a full worksheet, so I can define additional ranges as needed and have it populated to users without need for individual updating.

Basically, there are 2 processed that need to be done, the first process is already taken care of, but I'll show you why I need to copy multiple ranges

-Open Userform

-Select Brand

-Userform automatically populates multiple models based on Sheet2.Range("Brand")

-Select Brand2

-Populates based on Sheet2.Range("Brand2")

-Submit

Second process is

-Open NetworkLocation/Workbook

-Add Range("Brand3")

-Save


-Open Local Workbook

-Sheet2 = NetworkLocation/Workbook/Sheet2

-Userform populates with additional data for Brand3

Is this possible, and could you advise on how to proceed?

Thanks :)

Comment: So you want database functionalities in excel ?

Comment: Effectively, I think you might be right.  I haven't done any work in databases for a very long time, so forgive me if I'm a bit rusty.  In Excel I've got the local database saved, I just want to be able to update a network location and have the local location updated to match

Answer (score 2):

Okay, fixed it all up.  :)

And answering my own question lol - Just for googles sake.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Const fromFile = "NetworkDriver\Folder\Workbook.xlsx"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Sheet8").Delete
Sheets("Sheet9").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim srcBook As Workbook
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
' open workbook and set reference!





Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(fromFile, _
UpdateLinks:=False, _
ReadOnly:=True, _
AddToMRU:=False)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
srcBook.Sheets("Sheet8").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
srcBook.Sheets("Sheet9").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

srcBook.Close False
wkb.Sheets("Sheet8").Visible = False
wkb.Sheets("Sheet9").Visible = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```